# Sorted Sublist within a F# list of integers

Tags: list, recursion, f#, sublist

I am trying to get a sublist which contains the largest and then eventually second largest element from left to right in F#. For example if I have `list1 = [2;5;3;4]`  I should be able to get  `[5;4]`  as a result. `list1 = [2;1;3;4]`  would be  `[4]`  and so on. I can't really thing of a clever way to do this. I got following lines:

```
let rec top<'a when 'a: comparison> (xs: List<'a>): List<'a> =
     match xs with
        | [] -> invalidArg "xs" "Empty list"
        | [x] -> x::xs
        | x1::x2::xs' -> top((max x1 x2)::xs')
```

which gives me [5;5] instead of [5;4]

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: How should the algorithm decide when to stop? Like, in the first example, why is the result `[5; 4]` and not `[5; 4; 3; 2]`? Or do you always need exactly two elements and no more? But in that case, why is the second example returning `[4]` and not `[4; 3]`?

Comment: Because 4 is the last and largest element. The idea is to get the largest then eventually second largest, if it comes after the first, not before. Algorithm stops when it reaches the last element of the list. Its like getting the largest sublist and sort it descending. I don't intent to just sort `[2;1;3;4]` into `[4;3;2;1]`. I intent to get the 4 and then see if something  less than 4 is remaining to the right. So if the largest element is the last element, it should return it [4] for example.

Comment: Your additional explanation in the comment should be edited into the question. It shouldn't be necessary to read additional comments to fully understand a question. Remember that Q's and A's on SO is for the benefit of all that comes here later, and not just the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an auxiliary recursive function.

```
let top list =
    let rec loop n = function
        | [] -> [n]
        | [x] -> if n < x then [x] else  [n; x]
        | x :: xs -> loop (max n x) xs
    match list with
    | [] -> invalidArg "list" "Empty list" 
    | x :: xs -> loop x xs
```

or using list.fold

```
let top (list: int list): int list =
    List.fold (fun s x -> if s.Head < x then [x] else [s.Head; x])
              [list.Head] 
              list.Tail
```